# hibernate 4 mapping exception

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it mandatory to map my foreign key entity from ClassA to primary entity in ClassB?

In my case I have foreign key from ClassA maps to two entities in ClassB which is not primary key and it still works in hibernate 3.

But in hibernate 4 it throws MappingException

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK2C47CFCAB95CF1D:TABLE1 [COL1,COL2])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (TABLE2 [COL_PRIMARY])

How can I resolve the same?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the using composite key in one table as primary key. Though what you are trying to achieve should be possible.

Please see the answer of similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981881/org-hibernate-mappingexception-foreign-key-fk12a711396456ca10-must-have-same), hopefully you should be all set.

Comment: I don't have composite primary key in any of the table in database. I have only one primary key in TABLE2. from TABLE1 there is composite mapping using @JoinColumn for 2 entities in TABLE2.

Comment: **FK2C47CFCAB95CF1D:TABLE1 [COL1,COL2])** - It is saying that Table1 has two keys!